# How can I ignore the next/all newline after the command?

Tags: macros

For example, after `\paragraph{1}`, all newlines will be ignored and the next text will start next to the paragraph name. I want to add to my command something that will also ignore the next newline, so that I can leave an empty line after the command, but so that latex still continues writing next to my command output. In more details, I want

```
\cmd{Hi}

Bye
```

To yield

```
Hi Bye
```

but right now it gives me

```
Hi
Bye
```

If I replace `cmd` with `paragraph`, the desired output will be achieved, so there has to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution inspired by `\@xsect`

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\my@pseudo@xsect}[1]{%
  \@nobreakfalse
  \global\@noskipsectrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@noskipsec
      \global\@noskipsecfalse
     {\setbox\z@\lastbox}% remove paragraph indentation
      \my@stored@stuff
      \hspace{#1}%         you could remove this, use a control space, etc.
    \else
      \everypar{}%         restore \everypar
    \fi}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\newcommand*{\my@stored@stuff}{} % make sure the name isn't already taken

% The optional argument is the amount of horizontal glue inserted after the
% “first part.” It is passed to the \hspace command in \my@pseudo@xsect, which
% could be removed if no space is wanted, replaced by a control space,
% whatever.
\newcommand*{\mycmd}[2][1em]{%
  \if@noskipsec\leavevmode\fi \par
  \renewcommand*{\my@stored@stuff}{\emph{#2}}% for instance
  \my@pseudo@xsect{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\bigskip
\mycmd{Hi!}

Bye.

\bigskip
\mycmd[0pt]{With zero-width glue:}

I am very close to the colon!

\bigskip
\mycmd{A list environment follows:}

\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{itemize}

\bigskip
\mycmd[0.7em]{This also works:} because of the \verb|\par| in \verb|\mycmd|.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to understand how this works, read the next part.

## Direct use of `\@xsect`

What follows is the first version of the answer. The code is shorter than what I posted above since it reuses `\@xsect`. It has little side effects that might be undesirable for you, though (most notably, the setting of `\clubpenalty` to 10000). Use it if you want your command to behave like a pseudo-`\paragraph`.

So, we can reuse the machinery `\paragraph` relies on: `\@xsect`, when given a non-positive skip as argument:

1. doesn't prevent a page break before the line containing the run-in section title (see the `\@nobreakfalse` in code at the end of this answer), and;
2. redefines `\everypar` so that when the next paragraph starts, all of the following operations are performed:

   - the indentation box is removed (`\setbox\z@\lastbox`);
   - no page break will be allowed after the first line of the paragraph (`\clubpenalty` set to 10000);
   - the `\@svsechd` macro is expanded and its code executed inside a group (this normally typesets the run-in “section” number and title, where “section” stands for a `\paragraph` or `\subparagraph`);
   - if this left glue as the last item of the current list (hopefully, a horizontal one), it is removed using `\unskip`;
   - a horizontal skip which is the opposite of the argument of `\@xsect` is inserted;
   - all these things done by the modified `\everypar` are one-shot: when the next paragraph starts, the standard value of `\clubpenalty` is restored (LaTeX previously saved it in `\@clubpenalty`) and `\everypar` is reset to the empty token list (i.e., it won't do anything for subsequent paragraphs).

Thus, if your command redefines `\@svsechd` to typeset your “Hi” the way you want and then calls `\@xsect` with a negative skip as argument, this machinery will print your “Hi”, insert horizontal glue using the opposite of the skip argument given to `\@xsect`, expand what follows ignoring space tokens (because `\@xsect` ends with `\ignorespaces`) and finally, you'll have the “Bye” that triggered the paragraph start that caused the modified `\everypar` to typeset your “Hi”. (Deep breath.) You got that? :-)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mycmd}[1]{%
  \if@noskipsec\leavevmode\fi \par
  \def\@svsechd{\emph{#1}}%
  % Horizontal glue inserted will be 1em. With 0em, “Hi!” and “Bye” would be
  % stuck to each other.
  \@xsect{-1em}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mycmd{Hi!}

Bye.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the little side effects such as `\clubpenalty` being set to 10000, you can copy the interesting part of `\@xsect` to a macro of yours without for instance the `\clubpenalty\@M`, and use the modified macro instead of `\@xsect` (that is precisely what we did in the first example). In the end, this boils down to storing whatever needs to be stored, assigning a new value to `\everypar` that, when the next paragraph starts, first yields contents using what has been stored, then arranges things so that the next time a paragraph is started, things will be back to normal.

There are certainly other ways to do something like that, such as temporarily redefining `\par` or writing a macro that gobbles `\par` tokens.

For reference, the part of `\@xsect` that I described above is:

```latex
\def\@xsect#1{%
  \@tempskipa #1\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    ... % irrelevant to this discussion (non-run-in headings)
  \else % this is the case concerning run-in headings
    \@nobreakfalse
    \global\@noskipsectrue
    \everypar{%
      \if@noskipsec
        \global\@noskipsecfalse
       {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
        \clubpenalty\@M
        \begingroup \@svsechd \endgroup
        \unskip
        \@tempskipa #1\relax
        \hskip -\@tempskipa
      \else
        \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
        \everypar{}%
      \fi}%
  \fi
  \ignorespaces}
```

Comment: I updated the answer, you may want to reread it (first code inspired by `\@xsect` but not reusing it).

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to implement this, however I still have one issue. When I do this, I have way more space above than with a my old command, which only contained `\vspace{1.5mm}`.

Comment: I'm lacking context on what you *really* want to do and an MWE of what doesn't work. The code shouldn't add vertical space except that it starts a new paragraph (as does `\paragraph`: this ensures that a previous `\paragraph` waiting to be flushed doesn't get lost). You may try to remove the `\if@noskipsec\leavevmode\fi \par`, but if you do so and there is already contents waiting to be released via `\everypar` when you use `\mycmd`, this contents will be lost. Depending on the constraints, maybe one of the other approaches is more suitable.

Comment: I suggest asking a new question with a MWE that exhibits the problem and a clear statement of the constraints, including: 1) Is a `\par` token (I mean, a blank line) *required* or only *tolerated* after `\mycmd{arg}`? 2) Should all consecutive `\par` tokens following `\mycmd{arg}` get eaten, or only one? 3) Should spaces be ignored after what your command produces? 4) Most importantly, do you really need to use such a strange syntax in the first place? It is not the easiest syntax to work with.